# cron library for java with 'spreading'

Tags: java, cron

I'm looking for a cron scheduling system with the possibility to 'spread out' tasks. Lets say I need to do a bit of work at 'round about' 12 o clock. The 'round about' is defined as lets say +/- 30 minutes. I need such a thing for my automated update task to not have all my millions of customers (joking...) downloading updates at exact the same time and just blowing up my webserver...

I know little about the existing cron libraries in java. I know there are cronj or quarz and dozen other systems - but I can't find out if one of them is able to do what I'm looking for.

At least I can implement such a 'spreading' feature (don't know how to call it better) myself by using a normal cron job and trigger a new Plain-Old-TimerTask with a little bit of Math.round() thingy... But would be nice if there is a native possibility for this.

Thanks and greetings

Answer (score 0):

This looks being easy to implement on your own.

Create a worker thread which gets a random timer, sleeps and wakes up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need a cron library for tons of other tasks too. To keep it simple I just mentioned my specific problem.

Comment: What are underlying architecture reasons you need cron library for?

Comment: My application is running as a service and is a base system for other types of services (plugins) depending on customer needs. Theses plugins all doing various kinds of stuff like "do uploading Foo every monday to friday to Server Bar" or "offer a webservice accepting incoming SOAP requests" or "Download thing X from Y, unpack and do nasty things with the resulting files" and so on and to forth... To not implement the wheel every time, I want to offer solid libraries for those "plugins". The cron-system is just one of them

Comment: Some things are easy to create. Like email sending scheduling or job queue system, it is usually enough 1-3 working days. Since I don't see architectural reasons to use existing cron library, it sounds to me like "Not invented here" antipattern.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you and I don't get the point. But why should it be wrong to use an already existing cron library if I really need such a system? As I already mentioned my system needs to execute various different parts of work. Some of them need to do their work at regular intervals like "every 15 minutes from 8:00 until 18:00 and from Monday to Friday", or "every Saturday at 22:00". Why reinvent the wheel and mess around with TimerTasks and/or plain Threads and calculate each next execution if I just can use an already existing and proved library?